# Elasticsearch query against multiple types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two types stored in ES:

- Photos (fields: photo-id, description, createDateAsLong)
- VisitHistory (username, photo-id - with 30days TTL)

Is it possible to query ES for records of type Photos which photo-id doesn't exists in VisitHistory (for some username value). I mean a query which is equivalent of sql query like this:

SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE photo-id NOT IN (SELECT photo-id FROM VisitHistory WHERE username = 'somefoousername');

Answer (score 1):

If you make Photos a parent document and VisitHistory a [child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html) document of Photos, you should be able to use a combination of [`not`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/not-filter.html) and [`has_child`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-filter.html) filters to build such request.